# How to use a declared class multiple times in puppet

Tags: linux, puppet, devops

I'm setting up my firewalld services via puppet codes as below. My class refer to data hiera to fetch data

```
class profile::base::firewalld(
  Hash $zones                 = {},
  Hash $ports                 = {},
  Hash $services              = {},
  Hash $rich_rules            = {},
  Hash $custom_services       = {},
  Hash $add_services          = {},
  Hash $remove_services       = {},
  Array $zone_name            = [],  
){
  class{'firewalld':
   zones                                      => $zones,
   ports                                      => $ports,
   services                                   => $services,
   rich_rules                                 => $rich_rules,
   custom_services                            => $custom_services,

  }
  contain firewalld
  #remove firewalld services (ipp-client, samba-client)
  $remove_services.each | String $zone, Array[String] $services|{
    $services.each | String $service |{
      firewalld_service {"${service}":
        ensure  => absent,
        service => $service,
        zone    => $zone,
      }
    }

  }
  #add zone zPrivate zInternet zTier1
  $zone_name.each | String $zone_names |{
    firewalld_zone{"${zone_names}":
      ensure => present,
      target => 'default',
      purge_rich_rules => true,
      purge_services   => true,   
      purge_ports      => true,  
    }
  }
```

I want to use this class multiple times. For example. If I want to re-use the profile::base::firewalld but I dont know how to refer to hiera data with differens variables. Can someone provide my good way to solve my issue. The codes below is my approach but it does not work

```
class profile::bs::firewalld(
  Hash $zones                 = {},
  Hash $ports                 = {},
  Hash $services              = {},
  Hash $rich_rules            = {},
  Hash $custom_services       = {},
  Hash $add_services          = {},
  Hash $remove_services       = {},
  Array $zone_name            = [],  
){

  include profile::base::firewalld
}
```

Comment: When you say "I want to use this class multiple times", is that supposed to imply that it should have a different effect each time you use it?  If so, then you're looking for a defined type, not a class.

Comment: As John says, if you want to apply a class more than once, with different parameters each time, you actually want a defined type. They are documented at https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/lang_defined_types.html

Comment: That is a good idea . thanks you guys a lot